# Slick slider is not working properly in Magento2.3

Tags: magento2.3, jquery, phtml, slider, compare

I would like to use slick slider concept for compare products so I have implemented it on my Magento site. But It's not working as expected though the script has been loaded. I'm not sure where am I wrong.

I have included the code as well as the screenshot of my output for better understanding.

**Code in template file:**

```
    <div id="collapse" class="collapse prolist-compare-corosel">
    <div class="compare-arrow"></div>
    <div class="overslide" id="overslide">

        <section class="regular sliderfull slideleft slideshow">
            <ul id="compare-items" class="product-items product-items-names bxfrcmp" data-bind="foreach: compareProducts().items, afterAdd: initSlider">
                <div class="cardshape widthall removeslide">
                    <input type="hidden" class="compare-item-id" data-bind="value: id" />
                    <a href="#" data-bind="attr: {'data-post': remove_url}" title="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Remove This Item') ?>" class="action delete cancelclose remove-slide">
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('&times;') ?></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="" class="imagechange">
                        <img data-bind="attr: {'src' : image_src}" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <div class="textwordcont">
                        <p class="model-name">
                            <a data-bind="attr: {href: product_url}, html: name" class="product-item-link productword"></a>
                        </p>

                        <p class="moneyd">$3,499.99</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </ul>

        </section>

        <section class="otherwid">
            <p class="comparecolor" id="block-compare-heading" role="heading" aria-level="2">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Compare') ?>
                    (<span class="nocolor counter qty no-display" data-bind="text: compareProducts().countCaption, css: {'no-display': !compareProducts().count}"></span>)
            </p>
            <button type="button" class="clearall" id="clearall">
                <a id="compare-clear-all" href="#" class="action clear" data-post="<?=$block->escapeHtml(
                    $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\Compare')->getPostDataClearList()
                ) ?>">
                    <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('CLEAR ALL') ?></span>
                </a>
            </button>
            <a data-bind="attr: {'href': compareProducts().listUrl}" class="btn btn-colour-1 visible action compare primary"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('COMPARE') ?></span></a>
            <!--<input type="button" class="btn btn-colour-1 visible" onclick="location.href='#';" value="COMPARE" />-->
            <!--<input type="button" class="btn btn-colour-1 visiblemob" onclick="location.href='#';" value="COMPARE (4)" />-->
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code in Script:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui'], jQuery(window).scroll(function(jQuery){

             jQuery('.slideshow').slick({
                dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrow:false,
    dots: false,
    collapsible: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    responsive: [
    {

    breakpoint: 599,
    settings: {
    slidesToShow: 2,
    slidesToScroll: 0,
    prevArrow: null,
    nextArrow: null,
    infinite : false

    },
    breakpoint: 999,
    settings: {
    slidesToShow: 3,


    },
    }
    ]
              });


    }));
       });
```

**Css File**

```
 .slick-active {
    opacity: 1.5 !important;
    }

    .slick-slide {
    margin: 0px 20px;
    }
    .slick-slide img {
    width: 100%;
    }
    .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
    color: black;
    }
    .slick-slide {
    transition: all ease-in-out .3s;
    opacity: .2;
    }

    .slick-active {
    opacity: .5;
    }
    .slick-current {
    opacity: 1;
    }
    .cardshape {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    width: 180% !important;
    height:127px;

    }
    .cardshape:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .textwordcont {
    font-size: 15px;
    top: -144px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 178px;
    font-weight: 500;
    word-spacing: 0.17em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    cursor:pointer;

    }
    .containers {
    font-size: 15px;
    top: 41px;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 175px;
    font-weight: 500;
    word-spacing: 0.17em;
    line-height: 1.3;
    cursor:pointer;

    }
    .sizeimage{
    width:27%;
    position:relative;
    bottom:46px;
    }
    .productword{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #333;
    }

    .moneyd{
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    cursor:auto;
    }
    .cancelclose{
    font-size:xx-large;
    margin-left:334px;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    .productword:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
    }
    .slideleft{
    margin-left: 15px;
    }
    .slick-slide img {
    width: 33% !important;
    padding-left: 52px;
    }
    .widthall{
    width: 357px !important;
    margin-left:-17px;
    }
    .sliderfull{
    width:85% !important;
    margin: 45px !important;
    }
    .overslide{
    width: 100%;
    border-top-color: #ffffff;
    border-top-style: inset;
    display: flex;
    border-top-width: thin;

    }
    .slick-next:before {

    /* background-image:url(carousel-right-over.svg)!important; */
    color: black !important;

    }
    .slick-next {
    right: -11px !important;
    margin-top: -54px;
    font-size: 30px !important;
    }
    .slick-prev {
    left: -22px!important;
    margin-top: -55px !important;
    font-size: 30px;
    }
    .otherwid{
    width:15% !important;
    }
    .comparecolor{
    color: #6b6b6b !important;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top: 27px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-left: -6px;
    }
    .nocolor{
    color: #a50034 ;
    }
    .clearall{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    background-color: unset;
    font-weight: 540;
    color: #6b6b6b;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    .btn-colour-1 {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #cc0041 !important;
    border-color: #cc0041!important;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    border-radius: 0;
    line-height:2;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    width:111%;
    margin-left:-21px;
    margin-top:28px;
    border-radius:3px;
    height: 38px;

    }
    .btn-colour-1:hover,
    .btn-colour-1:active,
    .btn-colour-1:focus,
    .btn-colour-1.active {
    background: #cc004 !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-color: #cc0041 !important;
    }
    .compare-arrow{
    background-image:url(compare-component-close.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 10.5px;
    margin-left: 598px;
    cursor:pointer;
    }
    .ico-compare{
    text-decoration:none !important;
    }
    .plus{
    background-image: url("compare.svg");
    padding-left: 23px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color:#6b6b6b;
    background-position: 34px;
    }
    .plus.minus{
    background-image: url("compare-added.svg");
    color: #6b6b6b;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    }
    .fa, .fas {
    opacity: 0.30;
    }

    .cont {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    }
    .modelcolor{
    color:black;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .visiblemob{
    visibility: hidden;
    }
    .prolist-compare-corosel {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -133px;
    z-index: 1001;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    /* border-top: 1px solid #bdbdbd; */

    }
.borderempty{
    border: 1px dashed #ddd;
}
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Duplicate here.. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/293148/slick-slider-is-not-working-in-magento-2

Comment: @Kishan, we have tried that but not working. That's why here I have asked question. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Okay sending you solution within few mins. :)

Comment: Can you Please check you've added css files properly ?

Comment: where you have added css files ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya I have updated the Css Please Check

Answer (score 1):

Here, I'm providing you few steps. How you can implement `slick slider`  in your Magento..

For more information you can check this module.. [Download Full Module](https://github.com/KishanSavaliya/magehelper-magento2-slick-slider)

I've created Sample Demo with **Slick Slider** that will help you to implement that in your Magento 2.

#### Step - 1 - Create `requirejs-config.js` file

Create `requirejs-config.js` this file here in module..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

Content for this file is ..

```
var config = {
    paths: {
        slick: 'Vendor_Module/js/slick'
    },
    shim: {
        slick: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

#### Step - 2 - Add `slick.js` and `slick.min.js` files

You can download latest version of [slick here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Download that and extract .zip file and copy `slick.js` and `slick.min.js` files from there and paste that here..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/slick.js

and

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/slick.min.js

#### Step - 3 - Now add `slick.less` and `slick-theme.less` files

Copy `.less` files from downloaded directory to below mentioned path..

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/slick.less

and

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/slick-theme.less

#### Step - 4 - create `_module.less` file

Now create `_module.less` file here..

> `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/source/_module.less`

**This is important file to run slick slider properly in Magento 2 without any issues.**

Content for this file is..

```
@import 'slick.less';
@import 'slick-theme.less';
```

#### Step - 5 - Run following commands

- We need to run following commands to check output properly

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

Please do not forget to run this command here..

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
```

That's it. Now you can use slick slider in your template files like this..

```
<section class="regular slider">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
        </img>
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
        </img>
    </div>
</section>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require(['jquery', 'jquery/ui', 'slick'], function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".regular").slick({
                dots: true,
                infinite: true,
                slidesToShow: 3,
                slidesToScroll: 3
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Hope this will helpful to you!!